# Passing date into NSURL

Tags: nsdate, nsurl

I m trying to pass date into NSURL but I cant success. if anybody know about that then please tell me...

suppose i have date like January 1, 2000

I m trying to pass it through NSURL but i cant success.

please help me 
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateFormatter and convert your date to yyyy_MM_DD format